# Eclipse Plugin for creating large java class diagrams from existing code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, class-diagram

I am looking for an Eclipse Plugin to create large class diagrams from existing Java code (free/open source).
I found some plugins that create diagrams from java code and vice-versa, but the project has a large number of packages (about 80) and classes/interfaces (about 1000-1500) and I would like to create a diagram for the whole code, with different options (for eg, not to include the interfaces in the generated diagram or to create diagrams for certain packages).
I know that the diagram would be very big, but that is what I really want to represent the project in a single diagram (and omitting unimportant classes, interfaces, packages etc and also members and method names).

Answer (score 3):

Try [ObjectAid UML Explorer](http://www.objectaid.com/home). And you should also try [JUPE](http://jupe.binaervarianz.de/).

Comment: Can the plugin create a diagram from a specified package(s) ? or do I have to select each class that I want to represent in my diagram ? :)

Comment: @ice13ill use ObjectAid. It gets what you want.

Comment: I installed it, but i cannot seam to make it generate a diagram from "src" classes (or classes from any other packege). Do i have to select each class from each package if i want to include them all (or almost all let's say...)

Comment: Anyway, I expanded my project tree and added all the clases (about 1000) to my new diagram. Unfortunately, my eclipse freezes every time I scroll the diagram (for about 2 min) . Also, it seams the diagram generated has a width/height ratio of about 100/1

Comment: Well, it seams I'll have to create separate diagrams for different layers/systems/packages after all... Even so, it would be probably difficult (showing only public methods) to represent almost all classes.

Answer (score 2):

The project size is impressive. Before you will start with diagrams, try to answer to the following questions:

- how many diagrams will you create (approximately) ?
- how much time do you spent on one diagram (average) ?
- what are total estimated and allowed time effort ?
- is the result worth of the effort ?
- is the structure changing ?
- how much time effort has to be put into diagrams review+fixes after synchronization of model with changed code ?
- how much time effort has to be put into maintenance of diagrams ?

In case of project of mentioned size, most likely results are not worth of the effort and most likely model and diagrams will be continuously out-dated.

I faced similar situation even with much smaller projects (< 100 class units). I tried some standalone tools - the best was [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) (commercial), next - JUDE (currently [astah*](http://astah.net/editions/community), but they cut off import functionality from community edition). However, they and other tools didn't discover dependencies, didn't show parametrized types (List<Something>) and didn't show annotations.

So finally I started to use free UML browser/navigator - [Class Visualizer](http://www.class-visualizer.net/).
It's like using interactive map versus scanned paper map.
It allows to see selected class with all its relations: super-classes, implemented interfaces, sub-classes, referenced classes (associations, dependencies), usages (associations, dependencies). It processes and shows parametrized types and annotations. I can navigate to other classes through relations. Selected class is presented with all details, relations - without.
I tried it on projects of your size - diagrams containing hundreds of relations are generated instantly. And its repository is compiled java project, so no problems with synchronization of model with code.